# How to declare type of an object created dinamicaly by for await in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, for-await

`for await (account of accounts) { ... }`
Emit an error: "error TS2552: Cannot find name 'account'. Did you mean 'accounts'?"
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have smth like that:

```js
const accounts = [1, 2, 3];

(async () => {
    for await (const account of accounts) { }
})()
```

In this case, there is no need to explicitly type `account` const because TS is able to infer the type.

If you still want to use explicit type, you can declare your variable before the `for  loop`:

```js
const accounts: any[] = [1, 2, 3];

(async () => {
    let account: string;
    for await (account of accounts) { }
})()
```